# Tag Synonym request: [task-scheduler] vs. [windows-task-scheduler]

Tags: discussion, tag-synonym-request

A pair of tags I came across on Super User - both [task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-scheduler) and [windows-task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-task-scheduler) exist, but as far I can see they're both the same thing:

[task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-scheduler): a component in Windows that, like the unix cron daemon, allows scripts to be run at defined times. ([questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-scheduler))

[windows-task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-task-scheduler): a component of Microsoft Windows that provides the ability to schedule the launch of programs or scripts at predefined times ([questions](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-task-scheduler))

Some of the questions are tagged with both.

**Edit:** This is a clearcut synonym request that was raised over 5 years ago but has not been acted on.  It was bumped 2 years ago by incorporating it into another tag cleanup effort and making it a duplicate of that.  However, it didn't get handled then, either.  The [task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-scheduler) tag has recently been cleaned up in preparation for making it a synonym.  Please reopen this question and synonomize the tags.

Comment: http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6334/tag-synonym-request-tagtask-scheduler-vs-tagwindows-task-scheduler

Comment: @Raystafarian: your link points back to this same question.  Were you going for emphasis?  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234 hm, I don't know. I think I was trying http://meta.superuser.com/questions/9189/windows-task-scheduler-and-task-scheduler-are-the-same

Comment: "This question has been asked before and already has an answer." The answered question was asked two years after mine :P I get it but it's cheeky copy in this case

Comment: Your proposed synonym should have been implemented 5 yrs ago.  We tried to bump the issue with the Rat's nest question 2 yrs ago because other tags were also tied in, and it looks like we dropped the ball.  I just left a message in the Ask a Mod chat room to see if we can get the request implemented.  Think of your suggestion as fine wine; it needed to age.  :-)

Comment: **This needs to be re-opened.** As noted by @fixer1234 it was closed with good intentions but too many other tasks *(cough)* were proposed by the duplicate and this easy to solve synonym request was lost in the fray.

Comment: Well, it's been a few years and it seems this is still an issue.

Comment: I mean ... I'd have done it myself if I could XD