# windows-task-scheduler and task-scheduler are the same

Tags: support, tag-synonym-request

[windows-task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/windows-task-scheduler) and [task-scheduler](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/task-scheduler) have the same description. They should be synonyms or merged.

This is a duplicate of a request from a couple years ago ([Tag Synonym request: [tag:task-scheduler] vs. [tag:windows-task-scheduler]](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/6334/tag-synonym-request-tagtask-scheduler-vs-tagwindows-task-scheduler)), but that one got no response. I figured it was worth another try.